# TypeError: Product.findById is not a function

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js, sequelize.js, backend

```
exports.postDeleteProduct = (req, res, next) => {
  const prodId = req.body.productId;
  Product.findById(prodId)
    .then((product) => {
      return product.destroy();
    })
    .then((result) => {
      res.redirect("/admin/products");
    })
    .catch((err) => console.log(err));
};
```

TypeError: Product.findById is not a function

I am getting "TypeError: Product.findById is not a function."
I am using the mysql database and retreiving the data using sequelize. But it is showing error when I gone to alter the values(editing and deliting) in the databse.

I tried findByAll() .But it is giving the 500 status in the network console.

Comment: What Sequelize version do you use? Please indicate it in the post. Also it would be helpful if you show model definition and how you registered it and imported it in the shown module

Comment: In Sequelize v6 the method to find a record by id is named `findByPk`

Answer (score 0):

In sequelize ORM findById is not there instead of that u can try below code

```
exports.postDeleteProduct = (req, res, next) => {
    const prodId = req.body.productId;
    Product.findByPK(prodId)
    .then((product) => {
    return product.destroy();
    })
    .then((result) => {
    res.redirect("/admin/products");
    })
    .catch((err) => console.log(err));
    };
```

Or Else u can use findOne instead of findByPk

Happy Coding :)